# mvc route and get string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this route definition

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "test",
    url: "test/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "test"}
);
```

and this controller

```
public ActionResult test(string data)
{                   
    switch (data)
    {
        case "test1":
            return View("test1");
        case "test2":
            return View("test2");
        case "test3":
            return View("test3");
        default:
            return View("test1");
    }
}
```

and my url `...localhost:3598/test/test1`

But I get null data in parameter in controller. How i can get 'test1' in `switch (data)`?

Comment: Change the route to `url: "test/{data}",` (or change the method to `public ActionResult test(string name)`) so they match

Comment: You could pass the object(model) in when returning the view and then in your view only pick what you need. return View("test, data"); This way you wouldn't need to do the switch statement either, but simply return the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           name: "test",
           url: "Test/{data}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "test", data = UrlParameter.Optional }               
           );
```